# Unable to remove multliline comments using sed

Tags: unix, sed

In a file `sedd`:

```
/* This program read two integer numbers from the
   keyboard and prints their product.
                written by:
                Date:
*/

/*              statements */
  scanf ("%d",&number1);
  scanf ("%d",&number2);
  result = number1 * number2;
  printf ("%d",result);
  return 0;
} /* main */
```

Command:

```
sed -f sedd.sed sedd
```

where `sedd.sed` is:

```
/^\/\*/,/^\*\/$/{ d
}
```

`desired output`

```
  scanf ("%d",&number1);
  scanf ("%d",&number2);
  result = number1 * number2;
  printf ("%d",result);
  return 0;
}
```

I used `sedd.sed` as

```
$a\
\}

/^\/\*/,5{
d
}

/^\/\*.*\*\//d
/\/\*.*\*\//d
```

I'm not understanding why (below) breaks the code? The range with regex is not moving the pattern space forward I believe.

```
/^\/\*/,/^\*\/$/{ d
}
```

Comment: Works for me with Mac OS X (BSD) `sed`.  The braces really aren't necessary (just put the `d` after the range of lines), but they aren't damaging either.  If the problem was that data after the comment is removed, the problem would be trailing material (blanks or tabs) on the `*/` end comment line.  Which platform are you on?  Is there anything peculiar about the file?  Have you looked at it with `od -c` or a hex dump?  Have you tried recreating the file by copying and pasting the comment from this question into a brand new file, and then running the command on that file?

Comment: Thanks for such thorough reply. Kindly see update as I missed to add extra lines in the code.

Comment: What's the problem?  The new file gets more comment than you wanted stripped out, but that's just because you've not dealt with all possible configurations of comments.  You'll need to write a more careful script.  What do you want done with single line comments?  Replaced by a blank?  Left alone?  You should really show the output you're getting and the output you want to get, but your regex 'works' even though you didn't intend it to do what you asked it to do.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler agreed. let me do it.

Comment: I hope its clear now. See the update

Comment: @JonathanLeffler are you able to offer any help?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sed '/^\/\*/,/^\*\//d' file
```

If you want to edit your file with GNU sed "in place" add option `-i`.

Comment: sorry i forgot to add complete lines see update to question.

Comment: I dunno if it is relevant, but the question originally had the script marked as quoted text, and the backslashes were invisible.  When displayed as 'code', the backslashes are visible and almost identical to what you have.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear why you want to add a `}` at the end, so this script doesn't, but you can easily add it back into your script.

This script is not a generic C comment parser.  But it does deal with your input (but not mine):

```
s%/\*.*\*/% %g
/^\/\*/,/^\*\/$/ d
```

The first line more or less deals with single-line comments, as long as they aren't too complex (such as being embedded inside a string literal, or a multi-character constant, or there are several such comments on a single line).  The second is your original multiline comment parser.  It is OK within its constraints, one of which is that it doesn't attempt to detect general comments — only those starting in column 1 and finishing in a comment end marker as the whole of another line.

For this extended version of your input:

```
blurble
flup
/* This program read two integer numbers from the
   keyboard and prints their product.
                written by:
                Date:
*/
fangdoodle
wotsit

/* This program read two integer numbers from the
   keyboard and prints their product.
                written by:
                Date:
*/

int main(void)
{

/*              statements */
  scanf ("%d",&number1);
  scanf ("%d",&number2);
  result = number1 * number2;
  printf ("%d",result);
  return 0;
} /* main */

char /*far*/*deviousness(/*const*/ char *str)
{
    enum { MASSIVE = 128 };
    char *result = malloc(MASSIVE);
    char cmp[] = "/* not a comment */";
    for (int i = '/*'; i < '*/'; i++)
        printf("%d\n", i);  /* Note
                                this is not deleted */
    snprintf(result, MASSIVE, "%s%s%s %s", "/*", str, "*/", cmp);
    return result;
}

/*
 * This style of comment
 * is not handled properly.
 */
char *maliciously(char *deleted)
{
    return deleted + 4;
}

/* Oh why?
*/

whooptido!
```

The output is:

```
blurble
flup
fangdoodle
wotsit


int main(void)
{


  scanf ("%d",&number1);
  scanf ("%d",&number2);
  result = number1 * number2;
  printf ("%d",result);
  return 0;
}  

char   char *str)
{
    enum { MASSIVE = 128 };
    char *result = malloc(MASSIVE);
    char cmp[] = " ";
    for (int i = ' '; i++)
        printf("%d\n", i);  /* Note
                                this is not deleted */
    snprintf(result, MASSIVE, "%s%s%s %s", " ", cmp);
    return result;
}


whooptido!
```

Trying to eliminate C style comments precisely using `sed` is very, very hard.  You can more or less handle it for simple cases, but doing the job properly, recognizing strings and characters etc, is very tough.  And that's before you get into evil comments like:

```
/\
\
* This *\
\
/  /??/
* Trigraphs are going to go from C++17 *??/
??/
/
```

Pity the poor compiler writer who has to ensure that their compiler does handle such nonsense properly.